# Как сделать массив из значений в базе на PHP, MySql?

Tags: база-данных, php, mysql

Как можно сделать массив из записей базы, где к, примеру, есть только значение возраста - 14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполняете запрос в соответствие с вашей БД:

```
$sql="select zapis from table1 where vozrast=14";
```

А затем обрабатываете:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die("Query failed: " . mysql_error());   
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) 
    {    
        printf ("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
    }
```

[mysql_fetch_array($result, $type)](http://www.on-line-teaching.com/php/db.queryexec.htm)

$result - это переменная, полученная после вызова mysql_query()

Параметр $type описывает формат возвращаемых данных. Может принимать одно из трёх значений:

MYSQL_NUM. Функция возвращает нумерованный массив, где нулевой элемент - значение нулевого поля, первый элемент - значение первого поля и т.д. (поля считаются "слева направо" в том порядке, в котором были объявлены в запросе)